# How to resolve issue in this code with Java Streams?

Tags: java, loops, stream

The issue with the below code is the return value a2 only maps the last entry in the forEach loop, as a2 does not accept a list of entries, how can this be solved?.If there is a better way to refactor?, Can the inner forEach be replaced with a another .map?

```
finalList = Array1.stream().parallel().map(a1 -> {
    finalListType a2 = new finalListType();
    if (InterFinalListArray.isEmpty()) {
        a2.setId("text" + a1.getCode());
    }

    InterFinalListArray.stream().forEach(list -> {
        a2.setDisplayId(list.getId() + a1.getCode());
    }); 

    return a2;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: Hope it is understandable now?

Comment: Hi, what is the code for the `finalListType` class?

Comment: The finalListType class basically has lot of elements such as Id(mentioned only Id above), name etc that need to be populated in the finalList array, i am using the getter setter methods for that.                  finalList, InterFinalListArray have the same data type. Basically need to stream Array1 and InterFinalListArray(which sometimes can be empty) and populate the finalList array